# why CNN model change accuracy in each time? How I fix it for documentation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

First time I run then it got this.
[image: Accuracy of CNN]

The second time I run then it's got this.
[image: Performance of model]

I use same, batch size, epochs, and random_state=42. but not helpful.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide the complete model definition, model training, and model loading process.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.